# Wicket: Panel nesting as component

Tags: java, wicket

Is it possible (or what is the best way) to have own Panel with Component behaviours? Especially with HTML nesting...

I want something like that:

```
    public HeaderPanel(String id) { /* extends Wicket Panel */
        super(id);

        add(new Link(ID_HOME_LINK, null) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            {
                add(new Image(ID_HOME_LOGO, new ContextRelativeResource("img/logo.png")));              
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                setResponsePage(((BasicPage)getPage()).getLogoLinkPage());
            }
        });      
    }
```

With HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <wicket:panel>
             <a wicket:id="home-link">
                <img wicket:id="home-logo" src="img/logo.png" title="LearnMe" style="max-height: 65px;" />  <!-- HERE is problem - I would like to set children here -->
             </a>
        </wicket:panel>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the intent in Link (it is my "customized" panel that handles links):

```
public Link(String id, IModel<String> model, boolean ajax) { /* Extends Wicket Panel */
        super(id);
        this.ajax = ajax;
        this.model = model;

        setRenderBodyOnly(true);

         if (ajax) {        
                add(link = new AjaxLink<String>(ID_LINK) {

                    @Override   
                    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        Link.this.onClick(target);                  
                    }
                });
            } else {
                add(link = new org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link<String>(ID_LINK) {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick() {
                        Link.this.onClick(null);    
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

With appropriate HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <wicket:panel>
            <a wicket:id="link"></a> <!-- HERE is problem - I don't know, which ones and how many components go there  -->
        </wicket:panel>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I get this Exception:

```
Last cause: Close tag not found for tag: <a wicket:id="home-link" id="home_link3">. For  Components only raw markup is allow in between the tags but not other Wicket Component. Component: [Link [Component id = home-link]]
```

Maybe I am wrong with Panel capacibility or doing unnecessary thing with Link component, but I am looking for idea of nesting/inheriting Panels in one template like it is usual with Components in Wicket (like HeaderPanel Link were Wicket Link, not my customized Panel "Link" - that works, but it is not "common" solution).

Comment: You are adding 2 Links inside each other. Also you can use the FallbackAjaxLink that uses Ajax when possible.

Comment: Good point with AjaxFallbackLink - it seems that it is rendering href attribute anyway - that is what AjaxLink doesnt do and I was looking for.

But sometimes I want it to turn Ajax off - is there this option?

I think two links are "technically" ok, that doesnt cause Exception.

Comment: You shoould rename your Link class to LinkPanel or something similiar because that can cause confusion with Wickets Link class, then reedit your question for clarity, also dont omit extends statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `Link.html`. There you have a `<a wicket:id="link"` for the Wicket's Link but you do not have HTML element for the image. The one defined in HeaderPanel.html is completely overridden by the markup provided by (your) Link.html.